# How can I get Cosmos to scale back the partitions it has created

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I had a lot of data in cosmos but the costs were spiralling (up to 19 partitions). I've added a TTL of 3 months and the data is now far more reasonable (and should fit in 6 partitions) but it hasn't scaled the partitions back. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Why would the partitions have anything to do with the cost? As far as I'm aware  CosmosDB charges you for provisioned throughput and the size of items stored.

Comment: Provisioned throughput is divided by the number of partitions you have. So if you have 10 partitions and you have bought 30,000 RUs then you actually end up with a max of 3000. It sucks.

Comment: This doesn't sound right. Are you sure about that? Where did you read that from?

Comment: @NickChapsas This is exactly how Cosmos works. Your assigned RU throughput is divided evenly between the number of physical partitions in your collection. You can see the number of physical partitions and the RU assigned to them directly in the Throughput section of the Azure portal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft has not yet provided any way to control or optimize the number of physical partitions in CosmosDB. It can definitely be an issue if your Collection has grown significantly in the number of physical partitions especially if you are no longer utilizing all of that storage. You might consider transitioning over to a new Collection through using the Cosmos change feed or Data Factory. This would reset the number of physical partitions you are assigned and improve your throughput per partition for your new trimmed down dataset.

Comment: Yeah, this is the answer I got from Microsoft

Unfortunately transferring the data out and back in will reset the _ts field (I think) This will result in the partitions potentially being up to 2x times worse than they need to be as I will have twice as much data in my db before the TTLs kick in.